# How to iterate json object in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I am iterating JSON object in PowerShell using below code

```
    $awsFileResponse = '{
   "commitId":"opb274750f582ik",
   "blobId":"io6956a1a967243514e194lk54b86",
   "filePath":"PowershellScript.ps1",
   "fileMode":"NORMAL",
   "fileSize":5755,
   "fileContent":"7"
}'
foreach($KeyParam in $awsFileResponse)
{
    Write-Host 'Ashish'
    Write-Host $KeyParam
    Write-Host $KeyParam.NAME
    Write-Host $KeyParam.VALUE
    if($KeyParam.NAME -eq 'fileContent')
    {
        $fileContentResponse = $KeyParam.VALUE
        Write-Host $fileContentResponse
    }

}
```

I am not getting the exact output that I am looking for.

1. it is not printing anything for the below lines
   Write-Host $KeyParam
   Write-Host $KeyParam.NAME
   Write-Host $KeyParam.VALUE
2. it is not going to the inside if the condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not working as the variable awsFileResponse is not a Json Object but a string. So first you have to parse the string to a Custom Object . Then you have to loop all the properties inside it. And check the $keeyParam.NAME instead of $keyParam object for the fileContent key condition.

**Working code**

```
   $awsFileResponse = '{
   "commitId":"7cf4ca8ea129c2b9b274750f58245605e081580e",
   "blobId":"1d46ec453a6956a1a967243514e1944754c54b86",
   "filePath":"PowershellScript.ps1",
   "fileMode":"NORMAL",
   "fileSize":5755,
   "fileContent":"7"
}'

#Parse to Json Object 
$jsonObject = $awsFileResponse | ConvertFrom-Json;

#loop all custom object properties
foreach($KeyParam in $jsonObject.psobject.properties)
{
    Write-Host 'Ashish'
    Write-Host $KeyParam
    Write-Host $KeyParam.NAME
    Write-Host $KeyParam.VALUE
    if($KeyParam.NAME -eq 'fileContent')
    {
        $fileContentResponse = $KeyParam.VALUE
        Write-Host $fileContentResponse
    }

}
```